# Как исключить из серилизации родительский объект

Tags: android

Использую серилизацию Gson от гугла. 
Хочу сохранить (серилизовать) - объект **Fragment0**, который наследуется от **android.app.Fragment**, не нужные поля исключаю из серилизации при помощи **transient**.

Подскажите как исключить из серилизации сам родительский объект от которого наследуюсь (**android.app.Fragment**).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно исключить все поля (в том числе поля родителя), кроме нужных:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();  
builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();  
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Теперь нужные поля помечаем аннотацией `@Expose`, остальные будут игнорироваться:

```
public class ModelSimple {  
    @Expose
    String firstName; // сериализeтся и десереализуется

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    String lastName; // не сериализeтся и не десереализуется

    @Expose(deserialize = false)
    String email; // только сериализeтся

    @Expose(serialize = false)
    int age; // только десериализeтся

    String passport; // не сериализeтся и не десереализуется
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал, как вы написали - все работает :)